# Regex pattern questions in r

Tags: r, regex

I need to match author and time from string in R.

```
test = "Postedby   BeauHDon Friday November 24, 2017 @10:30PM from the cost-effective dept."
```

I am currently using `gsub()` to find the desired output.

Expected output would be:

```
#author
"BeauHDon"
#Month
"November"
#Date
24
#Time
22:30
```

I got to `gsub("Postedby   (.*).*", "\\1", test)` but the output is

```
"BeauHDon Friday November 24, 2017 @10:30PM from the cost-effective dept."
```

Also I understand `time` requires more more coding after extracting `10:30`.

Is it possible to add `12` if next two string is `PM`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can extract using capturing as a group (assuming that the patterns are as shown in the example).  Here the pattern is to match one or more non-white spaces (`\\S+`) followed by spaces (`\\s+`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by word which we capture in a group (`\\w+`), followed by capturing word after we skip the next word and space, then get the numbers (`(\\d+)`) and the time that follows the `@`

```
v1 <- scan(text=sub("^\\S+\\s+(\\w+)\\s+\\w+\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+)[^@]+@(\\S+).*",
           "\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4", test), what = "", sep=",", quiet = TRUE)
```

As the last entry is time, we can convert it to datetime with `strptime` and change the `format`, assign it to the last element

```
v1[4] <- format(strptime(v1[4],  "%I:%M %p"), "%H:%M")
```

If needed, set the names of the element with author, Month etc.

```
names(v1) <- c("#author", "#Month", "#Date", "#Time")
v1
#  #author     #Month      #Date      #Time 
#"BeauHDon" "November"       "24"    "22:30"
```

Comment: thank you for the help, I forgot I could use scan as well. Thanks!